# Android multiple activity status

Tags: android

I have 15 activities in my project.I want to show current status of user at the bottom of each of 15 pages the page.So user can get clue that how many forms are remaining to fill. I don't know any technical term for it.But it look like seek bar.
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html). set max value total number of activities and update according to current activity number.

Comment: Yes this is going to work easy.Thanks . Can i hide numbers like "1/15"

Comment: I think SeekBar does not show any numbers by default.

Comment: Yes this number is on textview.So I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) for simple navigation through iterations. Or use just one Activity and Fragments in `FrameLayout` or `ViewPager` if you want to show more complicated information for user.

Comment: I am using activity. I think View Pager is not work for activity

Comment: ok, but when you you fault with seekbar for activities, don't forget to use fragments)